# Рендеринг директивы angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

есть директива:

```
<div>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Phone</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="user.phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>City</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="user.city">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Street</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="user.street">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="UserListCtrl.addUser();">Create User</button>
  </form>

  <table class="table" class="user-list" ng-if="UserListCtrl.users.length">
    <caption>Users</caption>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Street</th>
        <th>Sity</th>
        <th>State</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <user-item ng-repeat="user in UserListCtrl.users" user="user"></user-item>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

В ней есть еще одна директива `<user-item ng-repeat="user in UserListCtrl.users" user="user"></user-item>`

Когда пользователь добавляется, то из верстки понятно что должно добавить элементы в table>tbody

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row">{{ UserItemCtrl.user.index }}</th>
  <td>{{ UserItemCtrl.user.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ UserItemCtrl.user.email }}</td>
  <td>{{ UserItemCtrl.user.phone }}</td>
  <td>{{ UserItemCtrl.user.street }}</td>
  <td>{{ UserItemCtrl.user.city }}</td>
  <td>{{ UserItemCtrl.user.state }}</td>
</tr>
```

Но когда добавляю angular добавляет под тег form вместо table>tbody

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот почему не стоит выносить в директиву только _часть_ стандартного элемента

Comment: это особенность обработки некорректных элементов внутри тега table. Которая так же может зависеть от браузера

Comment: проблема решится если использовать директиву не как элемент а как атрибут `<tr user-item ng-repeat="user in UserListCtrl.users" user="user"></tr>`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо

Comment: вот точно помню, что отвечал на подобный вопрос, но найти не могу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, как браузер обрабатывает наличие недопустимого вложенного элемента.

В элемент `tbody` разрешено вкладывать *только* элементы *tr*. Если вместо *tr* будет что-то другое, то результат может зависеть от браузера

- может быть нормальное поведение
- недопустимый элемент может быть вынесен из таблицы вверх или вниз
- что-нибудь еще.

Так как в примере в `tbody` добавляется элемент *user-item*, то хром в данном случае выносит этот элемент перед таблицей, затем отрабатывает код ангуляра и элемент заменяется на элемент *tr*.

Чтобы избежать выноса, нужно использовать *user-item* не в виде элемента, а в виде атрибута

```
<tr user-item ng-repeat="user in UserListCtrl.users" user="user"></tr>
```

В этом случае внутри `tbody` находится разрешенный `tr` и выноса не происходит.